# Done button not firing Completed event on Xamarin Entry

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

After I've added the [Done button on iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/ios/add-done-to-keyboard/) numeric keyboard in Xamarin Forms, I encountered another problem: the Done button not firing Completed event (like return button does).
On my way to implement this, I found the following code on [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/164104/#Comment_164104):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using KeyboardTest.iOS;
using KeyboardTest;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryDone), typeof(EntryDoneRenderer))]

namespace KeyboardTest.iOS
{
public class EntryDoneRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
// used to cache the MethodInfo so we only have the reflection hit once
private MethodInfo baseEntrySendCompleted = null;
public EntryDoneRenderer ()
{
}

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged (e);

    if (this.Element.Keyboard == Keyboard.Numeric) 
    {
        // only want the Done on the numeric keyboard type
        UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar (new RectangleF (0.0f, 0.0f, (float)Control.Frame.Size.Width, 44.0f));

        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate {
            this.Control.ResignFirstResponder ();
            Type baseEntry = this.Element.GetType();
            if(baseEntrySendCompleted==null)
            {
                // use reflection to find our method
                baseEntrySendCompleted = baseEntry.GetMethod("SendCompleted",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
            }

            try 
            {
                baseEntrySendCompleted.Invoke(this.Element,null);
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                // handle the invoke error condition    
            }

        });

        toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] {
            new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
            doneButton
        };

        this.Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }
}
}
}
```

I don't know why, but I receive the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at myGame.iOS.DoneEntryRenderer.<OnElementChanged>m__0 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x0005d] in /Users/silviu/Projects/myGame/iOS/DoneEntry.cs:37
```

On that line I have the code:
`baseEntrySendCompleted.Invoke(this.Element, null);`

I’ve tried to debug the problem and I found that the `SendCompleted` method does not exist, but I don’t understand how to solve this problem in the lastest version of Xamarin, because I think on the moment when that guy posted the code, worked.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a complete hack to me...anyway, you could try to invoke the `Completed` event directly instead of using reflection. It's declared `public`: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5e553f6195e66e48688b8ab324f1bab1e9251f0a/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Entry.cs#L96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SendCompleted()` was actually added for `IEntryController` so you don't need to use reflection for this any longer. In fact it appears that way no longer works. Just call `SendCompleted()` directly from your button press like so.

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0.0f, 0.0f, Control.Frame.Size.Width, 44.0f));

        toolbar.Items = new[]
        {
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate {
                Control.ResignFirstResponder();
                ((IEntryController)Element).SendCompleted();
            })
        };

        this.Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }
```