# How to detect when user backs out of a text Entry without pressing enter in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, event-handling

In my Xamarin Forms app I have a page with an `Entry` view for entering text. I've wired up the `TextChanged` event so that the UI dynamically updates as the user enters text, and I want the updated UI to persist if the user presses enter (i.e. the `Completed` event is triggered) but revert to how it was previously if the user backs out of the view (i.e. the `Unfocused` event is triggered but not the `Completed` event).

The complication here is that - at least on Android - Xamarin triggers the `Unfocused` event first (in both cases) and *then* the `Completed` event (only in the case where the user presses enter). So it's difficult to know exactly when to revert the UI changes. This is counter-intuitive to me: when I press enter the view obviously still has focus, so it doesn't make sense for `Unfocused` to be called first before the `Completed`.

Some things I've tried and am not happy with:

- Inside the `Unfocused` event handler, start a timer for 200ms, and if the `Completed` event hasn't happened by then assume it's not going to and revert the UI (doesn't seem reliable, 200ms is totally arbitrary).
- Always revert the UI inside the `Unfocused` event and then reapply the changes in the `Completed` event if it is received (ugly, causes UI to flicker, bad performance).
- Some combination of the above, e.g: start a timer and then revert the UI changes after 200ms, but reapply them if `Completed` is received after that or cancel the timer if it is received before then (getting a bit complicated).

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: [A similar problem](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87705/switching-focus-is-broken-in-entry-completed-event-handler). But I don't think it has a proper solution

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521517/7196681), [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55183/done-button-not-firing-completed-event-on-entry) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39582265/7196681) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Changing your suggestion of timer a little bit. "entryFocus" is an entry name.

```
CancellationTokenSource source;
private void EntryFocus_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        source.Cancel();
    }
    catch { }
}

async private void EntryFocus_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(500, source.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) //completed event requested cancelation
    {
        return;
    }
    catch { } //something is wrong
    entryFocus.Text = "";
}
```